# PHP - RSS Duplicate items

Tags: php

I have RSS like this:

```
<title>Session 1</pubDate>
<category>Blue</category>
<category>Green</category>
<evnet:starttime>Mon, 15 Mar 2010 12:05:00 GMT</evnet:starttime>
<evnet:endtime>Mon, 15 Mar 2010 12:30:00 GMT</evnet:endtime>
```

Im using **Magpie RSS Parser** to get the RSS feed:

```
<?php require_once('magpie/rss_fetch.inc');

$rss = fetch_rss('http://live.visitmix.com/Sessions/RSS');

foreach ($rss->items as $item) { 
    $cat = $item['category'];
    $title = $item['title'];
        echo '<li class="'.$cat.'">'.$title.'</li>';
}


?>
```

The result is:

```
<li class="BlueGreen">Title</li>
```

I require:

```
<li class="Blue Green">Session 1</li>
```

**Note space between classes**

How can I insert a space between the category values?

Comment: mmm, looks like some nice HTML-injection too (XSS vulnerability). Always `htmlspecialchars` every text string output to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://firsttube.com/read/MagpieRSS-Bug-Fixed/

This post seems to suggest that it's a bug with magpie and they propose a fix that may help, although probably not a fix in the way you want.

You could probably edit the code further and just concatenate the categories adding a space between them.